# What is the core of a localization?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $(\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{W})$ be a relative category where $\mathbf{W}$ is saturated; i.e. it is equal to the subcategory of arrows inverted by $\gamma : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}[\mathbf{W}^{-1}]$.

The *core* of a category is the subcategory of all invertible arrows. $\gamma$ induces a functor $\mathbf{W}[\mathbf{W}^{-1}] \to \mathrm{Core}(\mathbf{C}[\mathbf{W}^{-1}])$.

**Question 1:** Is $\mathbf{W}[\mathbf{W}^{-1}] \to \mathrm{Core}(\mathbf{C}[\mathbf{W}^{-1}])$ an equivalence of groupoids?

This is true in nice situations, such as if $(\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{W})$ can be further equipped with a model structure. However, I'm curious about the general case, and have had no success working out a proof or a counterexample.

The saturation condition cannot be omitted; it's not hard to construct counterexamples if $\mathbf{W}$ isn't required to contain *all* arrows that are mapped to isomorphisms by $\gamma$.

I am interested in the answer to the same question in the more general contexts:

**Question 2:** The same as question 1, but the localizations are in the sense of $\infty$-categories

**Question 3:** The same as question 2, but $\mathbf{C}$ is a general $\infty$-category

Comment: Cool name, brother.

Comment: @DenisNardin Post that as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the saturation hypothesis on $W$, ignore what I wrote.

Comment: I don't see how $\mathbf{W}[\mathbf{W}^{-1}]$ sees the iso's in $\mathbf{C}$ which are not in $\mathbf{W}$.

Comment: @EdoardoLanari: The isos in $\mathbf{C}$ are mapped to isos in $\mathbf{C}[W^{-1}]$, and thus by the saturation condition, they are already isos in $\mathbf{W}$.

Comment: It is true for $\infty$-categories with fibrations, see Corollary 7.6.9 of [Cisinski's book](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/CatLR.pdf).